# How to link shared library *dll with CMake in Windows

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I have 2 files: `library.dll and library.h` with some code that I need in my own project. I'm working on Windows with Clion where I should config this with CMake.

I tried this way:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(test2)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
link_directories(C:\\Users\\Johny\\CLionProjects\\test2)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(test2 ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(test2 library.dll)
```

It compiled but didnt work. Returns `code -1073741515`

How can I handle with it?

Comment: Linking is correct. (It is not perfect, but correct). The problem is somewhere in your executable or in the library.

Comment: This question should not be marked as a duplicate. This question the first google search hit for how to add libraries to cmake, it's not answered, and the supposedly duplicate link is terribly outdated and does not handle DLLs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Although this question is old. You are targeting the link library wrongly.
`target_link_libraries(test2 library.dll)` is wrong. This is an example linking SDL2. In the main CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(GraphicTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/SDL")
add_subdirectory(SDL)

add_executable(GraphicTest main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(GraphicTest SDL2)
```

and in the library folder. Here SDL, add a CMakeLists.txt

```
message("-- Linking SDL")
add_library(SDL2 SDL2.dll)
set_target_properties(SDL2 PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE C)
```

Comment: Does not work for me. I get `LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'external_dll\Debug\hello.lib'` (using subdirectory external_dll instead of SDL and hello instead of SDL2).

Comment: The line `add_library(SDL2 SDL2.dll)` is wrong: it defines a library which should be **built** by CMake. For already-built libraries IMPORTED library target should be used. Also, it is impossible to link with `.dll` library file: it should be `.lib` file (import file).